# How can I show the full path to the current file in the mode-line for Spacemacs (Spaceline)?

Tags: spacemacs, mode-line, spaceline

I'd like to display the full path instead of just the filename itself.

How can this be done?

So essentially where it says `.spacemacs` in the below image (seems this mode-line is called "Spaceline"):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your `dotspacemacs/user-config` function:

```
(spaceline-define-segment buffer-id
  (if (buffer-file-name)
      (abbreviate-file-name (buffer-file-name))
      (powerline-buffer-id)))
```

Comment: Just as an alternative: put it in the title bar instead. `SPC f e d`, edit `dotspacemacs/init` to change the following value as follows: `dotspacemacs-frame-title-format "%f"`

Answer (score 0):

```lisp
(setq-default mode-line-buffer-identification
              (list 'buffer-file-name
                    (propertized-buffer-identification "%12f")
                    (propertized-buffer-identification "%12b")))
```